# Content Rights Management on Firebase

Tags: firebase, security

I provide some training content (video) on my app and I want to ensure that the content cannot be played from anywhere else (i.e. only available to devices that have downloaded and installed my app). The videos themselves can be stored in either my google cloud or aws.

Is this security capability available from firebase? Is there any code / documentation that may point me in the right direction? My searches so far have been fruitless but I must admit I don't even know what this type of security feature would be called.

Thank you in advance,
Andres

Answer (score 0):

There is no DRM functionality provided by any product in the Firebase platform.